# Drawing districts of large cities using google maps or openstreetmaps APIs

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, openstreetmap

Is it feasible to build a map using the google maps API or Openstreetmaps which has a superimposed layer that displays districts of a city? For example, Manhattan is a region within New York City, and I would like to be able to plot the boundaries of this region, and any neighboring regions on a map.

[image: New York City District map]

Where would one obtain the data for these regions (worldwide)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this can be achieved by using [overpass turbo](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) (which in turn uses the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)) and the [MapCSS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/MapCSS) styling feature by querying for all [boundary=administrative](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aboundary=administrative) relations with a certain [admin_level=*](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3aadmin_level) tag (*6* is for US counties). Although I'm not quite sure if the random colorization is actually possible.

Take [this example](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/vW) as a start and see if you can improve it.

Answer (score -3):

> Is it feasible to build a map using the google maps API or Openstreetmaps which has a superimposed layer that displays districts of a city?

It is possible.  Feasible is up to you.

I generated this map at [OpenStreetMap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

[image: Map of New York City]

> Where would one obtain the data for these regions (worldwide)?

Photoshop would be one place to start.

Comment: I think he is looking for an automated solution.

Comment: I wouldn't expect to go into Photoshop and find the co-ordinates for areas of cities...